# Netgear NAT over LAN TO LAN

Tags: vpn, nat, ipsec

I have the following question:

I need to connect through a vpn IPsec lan 2 lan tunnel with a partner but they want that I connect through a specific ip subnet which is not mine. Here's the situation:

MY SUBNET: 192.168.1.0/24

THE LOCAL SUBNET OF THE VPN: 10.178.51.64/27

MY DEVICE : NETGEAR ProSafe VPN Firewall FVS338

Is there a way to nat some of my ip into the subnet of the vpn, so I can use the vpn without change my 'real' subnet??

Thanks in advance